# Do Macs store a serial number on the disk?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, mac

About a year ago, I sold my old MacBook Pro. Last week I got a call from the buyer who said that it had been stolen and he didn't have the serial number — and did I have it?

I haven't been able to find it anywhere. It's not registered under my Apple ID (not sure it ever was). It was originally purchased from Amazon, and they don't put serial numbers on their receipts. I'm still looking for the original box.

OTOH, I do still have a disk image that I made of the drive immediately before I reformatted it, prior to the sale.

Is the serial number stored anywhere on that disk image?

What I've tried:

- Searching my current MBP for my current serial number
  I figured that if I could find a file with the current serial number, the old disk image might have that same file with the old number.
- Searching for old system profiler reports
  Sadly, I couldn't find one.

Anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reinstalling OS - Retrieve Serial number from filesystem](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3596/reinstalling-os-retrieve-serial-number-from-filesystem)

Comment: Nope—I read that one, and it's about an OS serial number (which Macs don't even have). This is about the serial number of the hardware itself.

Comment: For future reference, the hardware serial number is available from the system profiler, About This Mac, on the Hardware Overview page. (I know that doesn't help much without the computer in hand.)  If you've ever made an AppleCare support request, you were probably asked for it - perhaps Apple Support have a record of it.

Comment: @JRobert - Making an AppleCare support request puts the Mac's serial number under your Apple ID. As the question states, the stolen laptop was "not registered under my Apple ID"—so no, I knew that that wasn't an available option.

Comment: I understood this option wasn't available to you; that's why I didn't offer this as an answer.  But some future reader of this question might have different circumstances.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently the only ways to find out a Mac's serial number (if you don't have the Mac physically present) are:

When you had the Mac, you:

- Registered it with Apple (check [your support profile at `apple.com`](https://supportprofile.apple.com/Login.do))
- Ran and saved a copy of System Profiler's output

Without the Mac:

- Have a sales receipt from a retailer that puts the serial number on their receipts
- Purchased it from a retailer that keeps track of serial numbers
- Find the box the Mac came in

Thankfully, after I posted this question, the buyer was able to find the original box, which gave him the serial number.

But the actual answer to the question is: No, Macs do not normally store their serial number in a disk file.

Answer (score 6):

The computer’s “Serial Number” is not stored in the software, but the hardware as far as I can remember (because there’s a method in the Cocoa SDK to read it).

You can also ask the OS to tell you the Serial Number by going to /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app and executing:

```
ioreg -l | grep IOPlatformSerialNumber
```

This value, is stored in some form of nonvolatile memory on the motherboard, because you can wipe your hard drive completely clean, and the results will always be the same, *until* you have to change your board.

All that said, the vendor *should* have the serial number of the machine it sold, and Apple will know that the serial number went to X vendor. They have a decent control about that as far as I know.

So if you have the receipt from Amazon, then you can try contacting them about the issue.

Comment: Nope; I also thought that retailers had serial numbers. But we contacted Amazon before I posted this here, and they said that no, they don't keep records of serial numbers, with or without the receipt number or sales date.

Comment: @Dori apparently the only retailers that do this are the “official” apple ones and Apple Stores of course. I’m saying this because we didn’t have Apple Stores here in Spain (now we do) but I always brought my machines in an “apple reseller” and they keep tight control of that.

Answer (score 1):

Hold your breath... **MACs actually DO store serial number on the hard drive**. After finding MAC address from my backup, I proceeded further and found the serial number itself in the same `WirelessDiagnostics` archive.

Inside the archive there is a `wifi-BPpiyL.log` file which should contain the following lines:

```
<airportd[30]> _initSystemGlobals: Model name = <your model name>
<airportd[30]> _initSystemGlobals: Model number = <your model number>
<airportd[30]> _initSystemGlobals: Serial number = **<your serial number>**
```

I checked in Apple.com, and that was a valid S/N which showed the legitimate information about my stolen MacBook. Granted I've performed wireless diagnostics in the past and that's where these files came from, but it proves that if you have some kind of a backup, you have the chance in finding your S/N in it.

Comment: Where exactly did you find this file?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I had my Mac stolen and could not find the Serial No in the backup. The Mac used to be registered in my Apple ID, but is not any more. However, it still is in "Find My Mac", where I locked it.
Apple support wouldn't give me the serial number, saying they don't have it. However, when the police asked them which computers were tied to my Apple ID, they gave out the serial numbers.
So it seems to me that Apple does still have them, but is more cooperative with law enforcement than customers.

Comment: This is 100% correct. Apple isn't set up to validate the identity of any / all the customers but does have procedures to ensure law enforcement and lawyers are who they say they are. Any sort of stolen goods or identity issue is better sent through a legal/law professional as opposed to first person.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I'm sure lots of people are being redirected here from Google.

OS X may not have the serial number of it's device stored anywhere, but chances are you can find your MAC address, which, just like the serial number, uniquely identifies your machine. One example where the MAC is being stored in OS X would be *wireless_diagnostics-ilTACd.log* which is located inside Wireless diagnostics archive (if exists).

Comment: But MAC addresses can be changed, right? That makes them not very useful as unique identifiers.

Comment: Well you can 'mask' your MAC to not show up correctly in DHCP table, but you can't change your *real* mac address which is written on the laptop body (probably under the back cover) and can be easily seen in the OS X itself despite all the efforts of "changing" it. Thus if police finds ones stolen MacBook, they could easily tell if it's yours or not.

Comment: Come to think of it, I once got the motherboard replaced of my MacBook Pro and when I got the laptop back a sticker with the new MAC address was covering the old addres printed on the lower casing. So the MAC address is tied to the board, which can be replaced. I'm not sure though if my serial number changed w.r.t. the one written on the receipt.

Comment: Both MAC address and serial number are tied to the board. Replacing the board is like putting new computer (hardware) into an old chassis.